# Сумма по списку(см описание)

Tags: python

Есть список в нем данные (см картинку) таких списков много. Как сделать сортировка по названию (например: одно `Name=название` и в нем сумма всех элементов из `Name= длина` (у меня 10 списков в которых `Name=название,Value=1`. Нужно найти сумму всех длин из `Name= длина`)

[image: cписок[1]]

Comment: этот список в бд ? или как хранится?

Comment: этот список в одном из нодов Dynamo